# как записать словарь в csv?

Tags: python, csv

всем привет! Небольшая проблемка. Есть csv, его нужно считать и данные с определённых полей записать в другой csv. Исходный файл я зачитал в словарь, но при записи в конечный файл записывается только последня строка исходго файла, но во все строки где должны быть другие данные. Немогу понять что не так.

```py
import csv

d = {}

with open("dhl.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = ";")
    for row in reader:
        d.update(row)

        with open("DHL-VLS-Export.csv", "w", newline = "") as output:
            names = ['Sendungsnummer', 'Sendungsdatum', 'Absender Name 1', 'Absender Name 2', 'Absender Name 3', 'Absender Straße', 'Absender Hausnummer', 'Absender PLZ', 'Absender Ort', 'Absender Provinz', 'Absender Land', 'Absenderreferenz', 'Absender E-Mail-Adresse', 'Absender Telefonnummer', 'Empfänger Name 1', 'Empfänger Name 2 / Postnummer', 'Empfänger Name 3', 'Empfänger Straße', 'Empfänger Hausnummer', 'Empfänger PLZ', 'Empfänger Ort', 'Empfänger Provinz', 'Empfänger Land', 'Empfängerreferenz', 'Empfänger E-Mail-Adresse', 'Empfänger Telefonnummer', 'Gewicht', 'Länge', 'Breite', 'Höhe', 'Produkt- und Servicedetails', 'Retourenempfänger Name 1', 'Retourenempfänger Name 2', 'Retourenempfänger Name 3', 'Retourenempfänger Straße', 'Retourenempfänger Hausnummer', 'Sendungsreferenz', 'Retourenempfänger Ort', 'Retourenempfänger Provinz', 'Retourenempfänger Land', 'Retourenrempfänger E-Mail-Adresse', 'Retourenempfänger Telefonnummer', 'Retouren-Abrechnungsnummer', 'Abrechnungsnummer', 'Service - Versandbestätigung - E-Mail Text-Vorlage', 'Service - Versandbestätigung - E-Mail-Adresse', 'Service - Nachnahme - Kontoreferenz', 'Service - Nachnahme - Betrag', 'Service - Nachnahme - IBAN', 'Service - Nachnahme - BIC', 'Service - Nachnahme - Zahlungsempfänger', 'Service - Nachnahme - Bankname', 'Service - Nachnahme - Verwendungszweck 1', 'Service - Nachnahme - Verwendungszweck 2', 'Service - Transportversicherung - Betrag', 'Service - Weltpaket - Vorausverfügungstyp', 'Service - DHL Europaket - Frankaturtyp', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ausfuhranmeldung', 'Sendungsdokumente - Rechnungsnummer', 'Sendungsdokumente - Genehmigungsnummer', 'Sendungsdokumente - Bescheinigungsnummer', 'Sendungsdokumente - Sendungsart', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung', 'Sendungsdokumente - Entgelte', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gesamtnettogewicht', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP6)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP6)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP6)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP6)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP6)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP6)', 'Sendungsnummer', 'Sendungsreferenz (Retoure)', 'Absender Adresszusatz 1', 'Absender Adresszusatz 2', 'Absender Zustellinformation', 'Absender Ansprechpartner', 'Empfänger Adresszusatz 1', 'Empfänger Adresszusatz 2', 'Empfänger Zustellinformation', 'Empfänger Ansprechpartner', 'Retourenempfänger Adresszusatz 1', 'Retourenempfänger Adresszusatz 2', 'Retourenempfänger Zustellinformation', 'Retourenempfänger Ansprechpartner', 'Service - Wunschnachbar - Details', 'Service - Wunschort - Details', 'Service - Alterssichtprüfung - Altersgrenze', 'Service - Sendungshandling', 'Service - beliebiger Hinweistext', 'Service - Zustelldatum', 'Service - Zustellzeitfenster', 'Service - Vorausverfügung', 'Sendungsdokumente - Einlieferungsstelle', 'Sendungsnummer (Retoure)']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter = ";", fieldnames = names)
            writer.writeheader()
            for i in d.items():
                writer.writerow({

                    'Sendungsnummer':d["TRACKINGNR"],
                    'Empfänger Name 1': d["EMPF_NAME1"],
                    'Sendungsdatum': d["AUSGANGDATETIME"],
                    'Absender Name 1': "TS Autoteiel UG",
                    'Absender Name 2': "(haftungsbeschränkt)",
                    'Absender Straße': "Scheideweg",
                    'Absender Hausnummer': "42", 
                    'Absender PLZ': "26121", 
                    'Absender Ort': "Oldenburg", 
                    'Absender Land': "DEU",
                    'Absender E-Mail-Adresse': "info@ts-autoteile.com",
                    'Absender Telefonnummer': "0176-72165481",
                    'Empfänger Name 1': d["EMPF_NAME1"],
                    'Empfänger Name 2 / Postnummer': d["EMPF_NAME2"],
                    'Empfänger Name 3': d["EMPF_NAME3"],
                    'Empfänger Straße': d["EMPF_STRASSE"],
                    'Empfänger PLZ': d["EMPF_PLZ"],
                    'Empfänger Ort': d["EMPF_ORT"],
                    'Empfänger Land': "DEU",
                    'Produkt- und Servicedetails': "V01PAK",
                    'Sendungsreferenz': d["REFERENZNR"],
                    'Abrechnungsnummer': "52052678290101",
                    'Sendungsnummer': d["TRACKINGNR"]})
```

Comment: Всё логично, вы в каждой итерации цикла создаёте файл заново, стирая старые данные. Вам нужно создать файл один раз за пределами цикла

Comment: @andreymal а можно чуть-чуть подробней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упрощенное решение с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas

# __all__ column names in the source CSV file
names = ['Sendungsnummer', 'Sendungsdatum', 'Absender Name 1', 'Absender Name 2', 'Absender Name 3', 'Absender Straße', 'Absender Hausnummer', 'Absender PLZ', 'Absender Ort', 'Absender Provinz', 'Absender Land', 'Absenderreferenz', 'Absender E-Mail-Adresse', 'Absender Telefonnummer', 'Empfänger Name 1', 'Empfänger Name 2 / Postnummer', 'Empfänger Name 3', 'Empfänger Straße', 'Empfänger Hausnummer', 'Empfänger PLZ', 'Empfänger Ort', 'Empfänger Provinz', 'Empfänger Land', 'Empfängerreferenz', 'Empfänger E-Mail-Adresse', 'Empfänger Telefonnummer', 'Gewicht', 'Länge', 'Breite', 'Höhe', 'Produkt- und Servicedetails', 'Retourenempfänger Name 1', 'Retourenempfänger Name 2', 'Retourenempfänger Name 3', 'Retourenempfänger Straße', 'Retourenempfänger Hausnummer', 'Sendungsreferenz', 'Retourenempfänger Ort', 'Retourenempfänger Provinz', 'Retourenempfänger Land', 'Retourenrempfänger E-Mail-Adresse', 'Retourenempfänger Telefonnummer', 'Retouren-Abrechnungsnummer', 'Abrechnungsnummer', 'Service - Versandbestätigung - E-Mail Text-Vorlage', 'Service - Versandbestätigung - E-Mail-Adresse', 'Service - Nachnahme - Kontoreferenz', 'Service - Nachnahme - Betrag', 'Service - Nachnahme - IBAN', 'Service - Nachnahme - BIC', 'Service - Nachnahme - Zahlungsempfänger', 'Service - Nachnahme - Bankname', 'Service - Nachnahme - Verwendungszweck 1', 'Service - Nachnahme - Verwendungszweck 2', 'Service - Transportversicherung - Betrag', 'Service - Weltpaket - Vorausverfügungstyp', 'Service - DHL Europaket - Frankaturtyp', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ausfuhranmeldung', 'Sendungsdokumente - Rechnungsnummer', 'Sendungsdokumente - Genehmigungsnummer', 'Sendungsdokumente - Bescheinigungsnummer', 'Sendungsdokumente - Sendungsart', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung', 'Sendungsdokumente - Entgelte', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gesamtnettogewicht', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP1)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP2)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP3)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP4)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP5)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Beschreibung (WP6)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Menge (WP6)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zollwert (WP6)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Ursprungsland (WP6)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Zolltarifnummer (WP6)', 'Sendungsdokumente - Gewicht (WP6)', 'Sendungsnummer', 'Sendungsreferenz (Retoure)', 'Absender Adresszusatz 1', 'Absender Adresszusatz 2', 'Absender Zustellinformation', 'Absender Ansprechpartner', 'Empfänger Adresszusatz 1', 'Empfänger Adresszusatz 2', 'Empfänger Zustellinformation', 'Empfänger Ansprechpartner', 'Retourenempfänger Adresszusatz 1', 'Retourenempfänger Adresszusatz 2', 'Retourenempfänger Zustellinformation', 'Retourenempfänger Ansprechpartner', 'Service - Wunschnachbar - Details', 'Service - Wunschort - Details', 'Service - Alterssichtprüfung - Altersgrenze', 'Service - Sendungshandling', 'Service - beliebiger Hinweistext', 'Service - Zustelldatum', 'Service - Zustellzeitfenster', 'Service - Vorausverfügung', 'Sendungsdokumente - Einlieferungsstelle', 'Sendungsnummer (Retoure)']

# list of __required__ columns
cols = ['Sendungsnummer', 'Empfänger Name 1', ..., 'Abrechnungsnummer']

(pd.read_csv("dhl.csv", sep=";", header=None, names=names, usecols=cols)
   .to_csv("DHL-VLS-Export.csv", sep=";", index=False))
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую как-нибудь с пандой.

Comment: Я не опробовал ещё этот метод)

Comment: @Evgeny, ну тогда сначала попробуйте ... ;-)

Comment: Уже в процессе....